# On submit form conform dialog box is redirecting to another page and not waiting for conformation popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .enter-userdetails{
            width:500px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: #eee;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .modal-main{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: none;
        }
        .modal-inner{
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
            top: 0;
            left:0;
        }
        .modal-body{
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 500px;
            min-height:100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top:100px; 
        }
        .cansel-btn{
            width: 80px; background-color: #6c7135; padding: 5px;font-weight: bold;
        }
        .ok-btn{
            background-color: #6c7135; padding: 5px; width: 80px; font-weight: bold;
        }
        .btns{
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .show{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit").click(function(e){
        userName = $('.userName').val();
        email = $('.email').val();
        txt ="";
        if(email.length > 2 && userName.length>3){
        $('.modal-main').show();  
        console.log(userName);
        }else{
        $('.modal-main').hide();
        txt = "heyy  mahalingaaa You did not saved details!";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt + ' '+ localStorage.getItem('userName');
        return false;
        }

        $('body').on('click','.cansel-btn',function(){
        $('.modal-main').hide();
        txt = "heyy  mahalingaaa You did not saved details!";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt + ' '+ localStorage.getItem('userName');
        return false;
        });
        $('body').on('click','.ok-btn',function(){
        //$('.modal-main').hide();
        localStorage.setItem('userName',userName );
        var email =localStorage.setItem('email',email );

        //document.getElementById('mainForm').submit();
        });
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="enter-userdetails">
        <p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>
        <form class="form" action="savedData.html" id="mainForm">
            <input class="userName" type="text"/>
            <input class="email" type="text"/>
            <button  class="submit">Try it</button>
            <div class="modal-main">
                <div class="modal-inner">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="btns">
                            Are you sure you want to SUBMIT........?
                            <br><br><br>
                            <button class="cansel-btn">
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                        </div> 
                        <button class="ok-btn" type="submit">
                            Ok
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <h2 id="demo" style="color:red"></h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code, everything is working fine but whenever I submit the form, one conforms popup will open, whenever I press ok on popup then only it has to redirect to another page but now whenever I submit the form it is directly redirecting without popup confirmation.

Comment: You don’t have a form. (You do have a `<from` element however, which is unknown to HTML.)

Comment: Please add `<from>`

Comment: IF I USE POPUP IS NOT SHOWING

Comment: @RAMESH,@CBROE , on submit form conform dialog box is redirecting to another page IT IS NOT WAITING FOR CONFORMATION POPUP

Answer (score 0):

hope this sample may help :

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r8k0eL96/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".submit").click(function(e){
            userName = $('.userName').val();
            email = $('.email').val();
            txt ="";
            if(email.length > 2 && userName.length>3){
            var r = confirm(" Are you sure you want to SUBMIT........?");
            if (r == true) {
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
            console.log(userName);
            }else{
            $('.modal-main').hide();
            txt = "heyy  mahalingaaa Please fill up the form first!";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt + ' '+ localStorage.getItem('userName');
            return false;
            }

            $('body').on('click','.cansel-btn',function(){
            $('.modal-main').hide();
            txt = "heyy  mahalingaaa You did not saved details!";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt + ' '+ localStorage.getItem('userName');
            return false;
            });
            $('body').on('click','.ok-btn',function(){
            //$('.modal-main').hide();
            localStorage.setItem('userName',userName );
            var email =localStorage.setItem('email',email );

            //document.getElementById('mainForm').submit();
            });
            });



            });
```

```css
.enter-userdetails{
            width:500px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: #eee;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            }
            .modal-main{
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: none;
            }
            .modal-inner{
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
            top: 0;
            left:0;
            }
            .modal-body{
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 500px;
            min-height:100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top:100px; 
            }
            .cansel-btn{
            width: 80px; background-color: #6c7135; padding: 5px;font-weight: bold;
            }
            .ok-btn{
            background-color: #6c7135; padding: 5px; width: 80px; font-weight: bold;
            }
            .btns{
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            }
            .show{
            display: block;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="enter-userdetails">
            <p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>
            <form class="form" action="savedData.html" id="mainForm">
            <input class="userName" type="text"/>
            <input class="email" type="text"/>
            <button  class="submit">Try it</button>
            <div class="modal-main">
            <div class="modal-inner">
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="btns">
            Are you sure you want to SUBMIT........?
            <br><br><br>
            <button class="cansel-btn">
            Cancel
            </button>
            </div> 
            <button class="ok-btn" type="submit">
            Ok
            </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <h2 id="demo" style="color:red"></h2>
            </div>
```

Comment: this is not i want,i know default conform dailogbox ,i posted answer above

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. Here is an implementation

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .enter-userdetails{
        width:500px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #eee;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .modal-main{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    .modal-inner{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
        top: 0;
        left:0;
    }
    .modal-body{
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 500px;
        min-height:100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top:100px; 
    }
    .cansel-btn{
        width: 80px; background-color: #6c7135; padding: 5px;font-weight: bold;
    }
    .ok-btn{
        background-color: #6c7135; padding: 5px; width: 80px; font-weight: bold;
    }
    .btns{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .show{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".submit").click(function(e){
              userName = $('.userName').val();
              email = $('.email').val();
              txt ="";
              // write ur validation code here
            if(email.length > 2 && userName.length>3 ){
                $('.modal-main').show(); 
                e.preventDefault(); 
            }else{
                $('.modal-main').hide();
                txt = "heyy fukker mahalingaaa You did not saved details!";
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
                return false;
            }
           $('.cansel-btn').click(function(){
                $('.modal-main').hide();
                txt = "heyy fukker mahalingaaa You did not saved details!";
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
                return false;
            });
            $('.ok-btn').click(function(){
                localStorage.setItem('userName',userName );
                localStorage.setItem('email',email );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="enter-userdetails">
    <p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>
    <form class="form" action="savedData.html" id="mainForm">
        <input class="userName" type="text"/>
        <input class="email" type="text"/>
        <button  class="submit">Try it</button>
        <div class="modal-main">
            <div class="modal-inner">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="btns">
                    Are you sure you want to SUBMIT........?
                    <br><br><br>
                    <button class="cansel-btn">
                    Cancel
                    </button>
                    </div> 
                    <button class="ok-btn" type="submit">
                    Ok
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <h2 id="demo" style="color:red"></h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```